# How to unset a _SESSION Variable that is an Array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, session-variables, unset

I have a certain session variable that is actually an array. I want to delete the entire array variable but cannot make it happen.

**_SESSION VAR**

```
$_SESSION['auth']['id']
$_SESSION['auth']['username']
$_SESSION['auth']['role']
```

I tried `unset($_SESSION['auth'])` but it does not work. Do I need to unset each 2nd level array individually using unset()?

Thanks.

Comment: `unset()` definitely does work.  Your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Like Brad said, unset **must** work. Did you try setting `$_SESSION['auth']` to null ?

Comment: Ok, totally my bad. Long story...I built a routine that auto loads the session var from a persistent cookies. During my logout I attempted to delete the cookie and it failed. Subsequently, my _SESSION var got rebuilt by my backend script -- so there it was working. And the unset() was actually working too. It was just not effectively deleting the cookies. Sorry for the trouble and the silly question. But thanks for chiming in everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unset should be working :S As Artjom Kurapov also pointed out, it might have to due with the session not being started.

But anyhow, have you tried just doing

```
$_SESSION['auth'] = array();
```

Or if you don't care about the session at all, you could do `session_unset` or `session_destroy`

Comment: i think you meant to use a single "=" there. Otherwise you're just comparing it.

Comment: hah, lol, completely missed that ^^ Guess that's my penalty for trying to give a quick answer :P. But thx for pointing out @showerhead, it's now edited to the correct thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have `session_start()` somewhere before?